# Subir un resultado a firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Buenas tengo el siguiente código en android donde me muestra cuantas preguntas a respondido bien y cuantas no:

```
private void checkResults() {
    int correctas = 0;
    int incorrectas = 0;
    int nocontestadas = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < all_questions.length; i++) {
        if (answer_is_correct[i]) correctas++;
        else if (answer[i] == -1) nocontestadas++;
        else incorrectas++;
    }

    String message =
            String.format("Correctas: %d\nIncorrectas: %d\nNo contestadas: %d\n",
                    correctas, incorrectas, nocontestadas);



    //--cuadro de dialogo
    //construimos el constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //que va a tener
    builder.setTitle(R.string.results);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    //botones
    builder.setCancelable(false);//desabilita el bton atras
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.finish, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent b=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            finish();
        }
    });
    //volver a empezar
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.start_over, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startOver();
        }
    });
    //crea el cuadro
    builder.create().show();
}
```

lo que quiero hacer es que el resultado que se obtuvo se guarde a firebase, eh intentado con el siguiente codigo pero no me sale(la aplicacion se detiene)

```
String nombre = String.valueOf(correctas);
    mDataBase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("progreso").child("suma").child("pregunta1").setValue(nombre);
```

quedaria asi mi codigo

```
private void checkResults() {
    int correctas = 0;
    int incorrectas = 0;
    int nocontestadas = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < all_questions.length; i++) {
        if (answer_is_correct[i]) correctas++;
        else if (answer[i] == -1) nocontestadas++;
        else incorrectas++;
    }

    String message =
            String.format("Correctas: %d\nIncorrectas: %d\nNo contestadas: %d\n",
                    correctas, incorrectas, nocontestadas);



    //--cuadro de dialogo
    //construimos el constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //que va a tener
    builder.setTitle(R.string.results);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    //botones
    builder.setCancelable(false);//desabilita el bton atras
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.finish, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent b=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            finish();
        }
    });
    //volver a empezar
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.start_over, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startOver();
        }
    });
    //crea el cuadro
    builder.create().show();

// aqui implemento el codigo firebase
    String nombre = String.valueOf(correctas);
   mDataBase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("progreso").child("suma").child("pregunta1").setValue(nombre);

}
```

me sale el siguiente error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: com.juegosludicos.juegosludicosmejoradodos, PID: 26366
                                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
                                                                                            at com.juegosludicos.juegosludicosmejoradodos.PreguntaFacilActivity.checkResults(PreguntaFacilActivity.java:217)
                                                                                            at com.juegosludicos.juegosludicosmejoradodos.PreguntaFacilActivity.access$400(PreguntaFacilActivity.java:23)
                                                                                            at com.juegosludicos.juegosludicosmejoradodos.PreguntaFacilActivity$1.onClick(PreguntaFacilActivity.java:137)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
                                                                                            at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10620)
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21256)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

las lineas que señala es la linea donde implemente el código firebase

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: Que error te lanza? Muestra el logcat.

Comment: acabo de actualizar la pregunta amigo

Comment: Usa tu código como [recomienda la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users?hl=es-419), fíjate por ejemplo el primer ejemplo de código que ponen. En el código que has compartido no se ve por ningún lado de donde sacas el objeto `mAuth`, el cual al parecer, es el que está levantando el error. ¿Puedes mostrar dónde creas [tu objeto `FireBaseAuth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/?hl=es-419)?

Answer (score 0):

El error esta aca `mDataBase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())`

como especificas , se me hace que tienes asi dividida tu base de datos

```
JSLK2591LDL294K1-JKL ._ 
                       progreso._
                                 suma ._
                                       pregunta1:
```

bueno, el error que te tira es que no encuentra la primer clave, osea el user ID , para solucionarlo hay dos formas, una es habilitando google sign in en authentication en firebase , si no lo haz hecho hazlo, fijate si creas la misma id para el usuario con un setvalue antes, ya que si pides el currentuser.getuserid y no lo tienes creado en tu database nunca lo va a alcanzar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como no encuentra el CurrentUser hay varios problemas que pueden ser

```
>        1.- Que no estes logueado con google sign in o algun sistema de logueo de firebase
>        2.- Que tus reglas de authenticacion esten mal
>        3.- Que no tengas habilitado en authentication google
```

PD: si puedes compartir donde creas la variable mAuth seria de ayuda, o decirme dodne tu usuario se loguea, o como esta compuesta tu base de datos, recuerda que para que te obtenga el currentuser y el Uid el usuario deberia estar logueado y el `mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null` , haz un Log.e y chequea si `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` es distinto de null y te devuelve el id del usuario